# JS for loop inside of event listener is not reached

Tags: javascript

I'm building a simple html form and on login button click i update url, but the problem is that for loop inside of button event listener is not reached.

```
    var user_credentials = {
        "andrea@gmail.com": "password",
        "hospitalagency@gmail.com": "hospitalagency",
        "user@gmail.com": "password"
    }

    const loginForm = document.getElementById("form");
    const loginButton = document.getElementById("login-form-submit");

    loginButton.addEventListener("click", (e) => {
        // e.preventDefault();
        const email = loginForm.email.value;
        const password = loginForm.password.value;
        
        for (let i = 0; i < user_credentials.length; i++) {
            if (Object.keys(user_credentials)[i] === email) {
                if(Object.values(user_credentials)[i] === password) {
                    console.log("hi");
                    window.location.pathname = "/html/home.html";
                }
            } else {
                window.location.reload();
            }
        }
    });
```

Hi is never "printed", I dunno if it's the right word, but for loop is never reached. I tried to search online how to debug but i was not able to do it. loginForm and loginButton are not the problem, cause i tried with a console.log() and they are detected perfectly well. If you have any corrections on the code, they are welcome

Comment: `user_credentials` and doesn't have a `length` property. `i < user_credentials.length` will be false so the loop will not run

Comment: [How much research effort is expected of Stack Overflow users?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261592/how-much-research-effort-is-expected-of-stack-overflow-users) -> [Working with objects - JavaScript | MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Working_with_Objects)

Answer (score 1):

`user_credentials.length` will always undefined because its object, try to change it to Array instead.

Comment: This is a comment and not an answer -> [How do I write a good answer?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer)

Answer (score 0):

Here you can tweak the code

```
var user_credentials = {
  "andrea@gmail.com": "password",
  "hospitalagency@gmail.com": "hospitalagency",
  "user@gmail.com": "password",
};

const loginForm = document.getElementById("form");
const loginButton = document.getElementById("login-form-submit");

loginButton.addEventListener("click", (e) => {
  // e.preventDefault();
  const email = loginForm.email.value;
  const password = loginForm.password.value;

  Object.entries(user_credentials).map(([key, value]) => {
    if (key === email && value === password) {
      console.log("hi");
      window.location.pathname = "/html/home.html";
    } else {
      window.location.reload();
    }
  })
});
```